# SQL Server 2012 Query Multiple but not all Column Counts

Tags: sql

I'm building a query for an application in SQL Server 2012. This query is supposed to grab all sorts of statuses from a single table from SQL Server.

Tables are structured like this:

```
ProjectType | Team | ProjectStatus 
----------------------------------
 Proj1          B      Rec
 Proj1          B      Rec
 Proj1          B      Hold
 Proj2          B      Rec
 Proj3          A      Hold
 Proj4          C      Some
```

My wanted output would be:

```
ProjectType | Total | Team | Rec| Hold | Some |
-----------------------------------------------
  Proj1         3      B      2     1      0
  Proj2         1      B      1     0      0
  Proj3         1      A      0     1      0
  Proj4         1      C      0     0      1
```

I think this is possible because I know all the statuses they will ever be:

All statuses are

```
Rec, BA, DQ, P, Prev, PRed, PCom, 90, 90Rev, 90Red, 90Com, SS, SSRed, D, C
```

What I have tried so far:

```
select 
    ProjectType, Team, count(ProjectStatus) 
from 
    sites 
where 
    (ProjectType is not null and ProjectType <> '') and Team <> '' 
group by 
    ProjectType, Team 


select 
    s.ProjectType, S.Team, S.ProjectType, C.cnt
from 
    Sites s
Inner Join 
    (Select ProjectType, Count(ProjectStatus) as cnt 
     from Sites 
     Where ProjectStatus = 'Rec' group By ProjectType) C on S.ProjectType = c.ProjectType
```

Here is where I thought to add

```
Inner Join ( Select ProjectType, Count(ProjectStatus) as cnt from Sites 
Where ProjectStatus='Rec' group By ProjectType) C 
on S.ProjectType = c.ProjectType
```

Per status that I have in order to count them all individually...

EDIT: But the output is wrong it counted all the same ProjectType up for all different ones ( say i had 10 diff ones ) it displayed all the Same ones 10 times over

Is there a better way of doing this - Can someone help me complete?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c695/2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your question, it seems you have multiple statuses (all known) and want to show the counts by status -- placing the statuses across the top.  There are ways to do this using PIVOT, but I'm not at a computer with my dev resources right now, so this is how I would do it (out of my head -- untested).

```
select 
  ProjectType,
  count(*) as Total,
  Team,
  sum(case when ProjectStatus = 'Rec' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Rec',
  sum(case when ProjectStatus = 'Hold' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Hold',
  sum(case when ProjectStatus = 'Some' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Some'
from
  sites
where
  ProjectStatus in ('Rec', 'Hold', 'Some')
group by
  ProjectType,
  Team
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c695/2)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think i can get started with this , the Count(*) as Total however should be counting just for that ProjectType as in counting only the ( rec,BA,DQ... and so on ) for that ProjectType. Have not tested this either just yet.

Comment: Dang there is 1 issue where i cannot find the right place to put it ... some ProjectTypes are empty ( null ) i tried adding on to the Where but seems to have no effect ideas?

Comment: What do you want to do with the `null` ProjectTypes?

Comment: Sorry , I have more columns that Are not needed for this query, some of the ProjectTypes are Null , but i simply used the Wrong syntax for the quick fix... I was checking ProjectStatus for nul and not ProjectType like i was wanting too.. Thanks for your help Evertything works perfectly!!